# Move a server from Google Cloud to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I would like to move a windows SQL server running in Google cloud to AWS, which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an AWS tool - [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) (to perform the migration quickly) and migrate to [Amazon RDS for SQL Server](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/) (which is a relational database service managed by AWS = less operational work on your end).